# ZMQ client-worker communication pattern

Tags: sockets, messaging, zeromq

Reading through the ZeroMQ documentation, I got a little lost when I discovered these three socket combinations. They are:

- DEALER to ROUTER
- DEALER to DEALER
- ROUTER to ROUTER

I understand that DEALER and ROUTER are replacements for the synchronous REQ/REP communication, so they become asynchronous and multiple nodes can connect. What I don't understand is how a DEALER can be either a replacement for REQ and REP in DEALER to DEALER (and also a router in ROUTER to ROUTER).

I was looking for a pattern that allows an arbitrary number of clients to submit jobs to an arbitrary number of workers processing (with load balancing) those and returning responses (and intermediate results) to the client (asynchronously, but sending multiple messages back). The client may also need to be able to terminate the work prematurely. I find the [documentation](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Request-Reply-Combinations) a little light in this respect (I'm not an expert by any stretch and may have missed the relevant section).

I'm happy to work out the details myself, but every time I think I found a suitable pattern, I discover another one that may be equally suitable (for instance these 3 patterns are equally suitable in my opinion: http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#ROUTER-Broker-and-REQ-Workers, http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#ROUTER-Broker-and-DEALER-Workers, http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#A-Load-Balancing-Message-Broker).

Any advice on the structure (which socket for which component to communicate) is appreciated.

**Update**

This is what I came up with so far:

```
import multiprocessing
import zmq
import time

router_url_b = 'tcp://*:5560'
router_url = 'tcp://localhost:5560'

dealer_url_b = 'tcp://*:5561'
dealer_url = 'tcp://localhost:5561'


def broker():
    context = zmq.Context()
    router = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    router.bind(router_url_b)

    dealer = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    dealer.bind(dealer_url_b)

    poll = zmq.Poller()
    poll.register(router, zmq.POLLIN)
    poll.register(dealer, zmq.POLLIN)

    while True:
        poll_result = dict(poll.poll())
        if router in poll_result:
            ident, msg = router.recv_multipart()
            print 'router: ident=%s, msg=%s' % (ident, msg)
            # print 'router received "%s" and ident %s' % (msg, ident)
            dealer.send_multipart([ident, msg])
            # dealer.send(msg)
        if dealer in poll_result:
            ident, msg = dealer.recv_multipart()
            print 'dealer: ident=%s, msg=%s' % (ident, msg)
            router.send_multipart([ident, msg])


def client(client_id):
    context = zmq.Context()
    req = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    # setting identity doesn't seem to make a difference
    req.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"%s" % client_id)
    req.connect(router_url)

    req.send('work %d' % client_id)
    while True:
        msg = req.recv()
        print 'client %d received response: %s' % (client_id, msg)


def worker(worker_id):
    context = zmq.Context()
    # to allow asynchronous sending of responses.
    rep = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    # not sure if this is required...
    # rep.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, b"%s" % (10+worker_id))
    rep.connect(dealer_url)

    while True:
        msg = rep.recv_multipart()
        ident, msg = msg[:-1], msg[-1]
        print 'worker %d received: "%s", ident="%s"' % (worker_id, msg, ident)
        # do some work...
        time.sleep(10)
        rep.send_multipart(ident + ['result A from worker %d (%s)' % (worker_id, msg)])
        # do more work...
        time.sleep(10)
        rep.send_multipart(ident + ['result B from worker %d (%s)' % (worker_id, msg)])
    print 'finished worker', worker_id


def main():

    print 'creating workers'
    for i in xrange(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i, ))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    print 'creating clients'
    for i in xrange(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=client, args=(i, ))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    broker()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It seems to be working quite well. Only thing that's missing is the communication from the client to the worker once the worker has started processing the work. I guess the best idea is to create a new control channel of some sort (pub/sub) to terminate the worker if required.

A few questions remain:

- Has this model any obvious weaknesses?
- What is the `IDENTITY` useful for? It doesn't seem to matter if I set those values (neither in client nor in worker).
- The first messages the workers receive are:

  `worker 1 received: "work 3", ident="['\x00\x80\x00A\xa7', '3']"
  worker 0 received: "work 4", ident="['\x00\x80\x00A\xa7', '4']"`

  Why is the first `ident` item the same for both workers? The way I understand the router to work is to assign random identities which it keeps track of. How does this work (and it seems to work in a small-scale example)?

Comment: Hello **orange** -- two questions: **Q1:** Have you spent a few days on Pieter HINTJENS' excellent and rewarding book **Code Connected, Vol.1** ( not on code snippets, but on conceptual thoughts about non-blocking, scale-able Formal Communication's Patterns -- worth much longer time, than a few days, indeed )? **Q2:** Are you sure your **.bind()** after **.connect()**-s scenario is in-line with Pieter's recommendations for setting up this intended messaging environment? Keep us updated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to my update, I found that the worker can connect to the backend of the server using a DEALER. The pattern and explanation can be found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=TxHgtl_sFmgC&lpg=PP1&dq=zeromq%20messaging%20for%20many&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q=zeromq%20messaging%20for%20many&f=false).

The client uses a DEALER socket, the server receives requests as a ROUTER on the frontend (asyn + many clients), proxies them to the workers (backend) using a DEALER socket (asyn) and the workers listen to the server's backend on a DEALER socket (asyn, no routing necessary, although ROUTER also worked).

> If the workers were strictly synchronous, we’d use REP, but since we
>   want to send multiple replies we need an async socket. We do not want
>   to route replies; they always go to the single server thread that sent
>   us the request.

One further modification is the replacement of the implicit dispatching of router/dealer messages with `zmq.proxy(router, dealer)` (`while True` loop in `broker()`).

**Update**

Apparently, this pattern uses ZMQ's standard round-robin routing. A custom task assignment can be achieved by the ROUTER to ROUTER pattern. In this case a client starts with sending a request and workers start by sending a ready-message. The broker manages a list of ready workers and if none is available shuts down polling for new client messages (thus using ZMQ's internal message buffers).

Comment: In your implementation do you need work with `ZMQ_REQ` and `ZMQ_REP` on the clients and workers respectively? Or just `DEALER-to-ROUTER`?

Comment: REQ and REP are for one to one blocking communication patterns which isn’t used here.